# Segment-tree construction: do we recurse into both children?

Tags: search-trees, intervals

This question is about segment-tree as described in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) Wikipedia article.

When constructing the tree (inserting the new input-interval), if the input-interval doesn't contain the node-interval we have to recurse into node's child, where child-interval intersects input-interval.

But what if both children-intervals intersect input interval? Should I recurse into both children-nodes?